# Button don't work in the lockscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

i have one button in the lockscreen to display a alert when is touched, i am just playing with this stuff and tried to do this, but when i touch the button it crash and respring to enter in safe mode. I am running it with theos in my iPhone.Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SBAwayView : UIView

@end


@interface SBAwayController

UIButton *myButton;
-(void)unlockWithSound : (BOOL)sound;

@end



%hook SBAwayController

-(id)lock{

SBAwayView *v = MSHookIvar<id>(self, "_awayView");

myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(21, 80, 100, 35);
[myButton setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[v addSubview:myButton];

%orig;
}

-(void)myButtonPressed{

UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title of Alert"  message:@"Message of Alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",  nil];
[theAlert show];
[theAlert release];

}


%end
```

Comment: Get us some logs. Install Crash Reporter from Cydia and then tail -f /var/log/syslog via SSH to get a "live" report of what is going as your tweak is running. It will print the log in the terminal window as it goes.

Comment: How its that, i tried to ssh my iphone and then  -f /var/log/syslog  but say command not found, in crash reporter app i have a crash log do you need the springboard crash log right?

Comment: I don't think you put in the tail command. "tail -f /var/log/syslog". Show me the crash input here. We could use the springboard crash log but it's a lot easier to get crash logs "in the fly".

Answer (score 0):

First try to debug and see function gets called or not.

then also its crashing then try to use autorelease

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title of Alert" message:@"Message of Alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",  nil] autorelease] ;
[theAlert show];
```

Comment: This won't help locate the source of the crash though. At most it will tell us if the method is getting called. Based on the OP I would say it is indeed getting called and crashing there.

Answer (score 0):

You needed %new(v@:) before your void;

```
%new(v@:)
-(void)myButtonPressed{

UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title of Alert"  message:@"Message of Alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",  nil];
[theAlert show];
[theAlert release];

}
```